# Count unique values with multiple criteria- Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, count, countif

I'm using **Excel 2016** and I have a sheet with 5 columns:

- Risk
- Control
- Control id
- Category
- Status

Every risk has more than control, and some of the controls are used for another risk, also some of the controls have the same name but another **id**, for that I want to count how many control I have for all risks without counting **duplicate id**.

I also want to count how many controls that it's category is high and status late without counting duplicate. Please I want formula to do that, without using filter.

**Data set:**

```
      Risk            Control              Control ID            Category         Status
      
      Risk 1         Tech System                1                   High           Late 
                     Construction               2                   Low            Late
      Risk 2         Tech System                1                   High           Late
                     Tech System                3                   Low            Done
      Risk 3             HR                     4                   Low            Done 
                     Construction               2                   Low            Late
```

Comment: Show you expected result. Will it `4` for first question `how many control I have for all risks without counting duplicate id?`

Comment: Yes, and for the second question (How many controls that its category is "high" and status "late" without counting duplicate) result should be 1

Comment: Include your own attempt at solving this.

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula to get count of unique `Control ID` to  `F2` cell.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(C2:C7,C2:C7))
```

`G2` cell formula to count `High` with `Late` status.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((D2:D7="High")*(E2:E7="Late"))/COUNTIF(D2:D7,D2:D7))
```

[image]

Comment: formula for unique Control it's work fine, but the second formula in G2 not working if I change some of data

Comment: Not working means what? Error, wrong result?

Comment: Wrong result, I try to change the second control category from low to high but still the result 1

Comment: Then what would be your result `2`.

Comment: Yes it should be 2

Comment: @Mike Then use `=SUMPRODUCT((D2:D7="Low")/COUNTIFS(D2:D7,D2:D7,E2:E7,E2:E7))`

Comment: Thanks for your help but I still show a wrong result. The formula was also not taken into account duplicate Id . I want to show the result of the unique value for high and Late

Comment: Based on your sample data then how is 1 not the right answer? The only ID that has category = high and status = late is ID 1. So, when ignoring duplicates, the answer is 1? The only way the answer could be 2 is if you ignore IDs. Something is inconsistent in your criteria, sample data, or output

Comment: you are right, but I mean when I do some changes like if I change id 2 from low to high it should be the result 2